# Uni-variate Moving Average Theta coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, time-series

Consider the Uni-variate Moving Average Models (MA models) MA(1) 
$$x_t = \mu + w_t +\theta_1w_{t-1}$$
or the second order moving average MA(2) 
$$x_t = \mu + w_t +\theta_1w_{t-1}+\theta_2w_{t-2}$$

or the The qth order moving average model, denoted by MA(q) is

$$ x_t = \mu + w_t +\theta_1w_{t-1}+\theta_2w_{t-2}+\dots + \theta_qw_{t-q} $$

Am trying to understand how the coefficient $$\theta_1,\theta_2,...\theta_q$$ are calculated?

Can someone help me on this how to calculate the theta coefficient for an Uni variate  MA process?

Sometimes I see examples like this xt = 10 + wt + .7wt-1, where Theta = 0.7 for an MA(1) process, am not sure how was this calculated?

Thanks,Kamal.

Comment: Hi, am not getting any response, hope the question is published on the forum.

Comment: Hi, can someone please share a clue or pointers to this topic?